# Splitting ReactJS onto multiple assemblies

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, reactjs, asp.net-core

I`ve got a modular .NET application, which loads controllers, views and components from assemblies as plugins.
Going to learn React (totally new to it) - and got a question. Does React support splitting it`s components into multiple assemblies and loading them at runtime?

Comment: Please read [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) then reconstruct your question.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it does.

I suggest you to read React [official documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html).

Almost every React component will produce some HTML markup for browser to show. The general idea of component splitting is to split HTML markup between several components like so

```
// App.js
class App extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return <div>
           My first component
           <Component1/>
        </div>
    }
}

// Component1.js
export default class Component1 extends React.Component {
    render () {
        return <div>
           This is internals of component
        </div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi @ww87 if this answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.